# Convert list in Scala to a formatted string

Tags: scala

How can I convert the `List(1,2,3)` in Scala to a formatted string like `"1/2/3"` with the List methods?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Have a look at [mkString](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List). In short:

> Displays all elements of this list in a string using a separator
> string (In your case "/")

```
scala> List(1,2,3).mkString("/")
res0: String = 1/2/3

scala> List(1,2,3).mkString
res1: String = 123

// def mkString(start: String,sep: String,end: String): String 
scala> List(1,2,3).mkString("@", "/", "@")
res2: String = @1/2/3@
```

Comment: note that you can use it without any arguments, dafault seperator is empty string `""`