# Format string with array argument in scala

Tags: scala

I have next list and string:

```
val s = List(JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject)
val data = s"""[${s(0)}, ${s(1)}, ${s(2)}]"""
```

Is it possible to pass list to `s` function, so I won't get list elements by index?

Comment: [Convert list in Scala to a formatted string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18685963/432903) `List("A", "B", "C") mkString ","`

Comment: Actually I have not just simple string list but collection with JSONObject elements

Comment: Are you not using `org.json.JSONObject` ??

Comment: @prayag I'm using scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

Comment: I don't you how you get type `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` but try this one if it helps -> https://gist.github.com/prayagupd/b17e0f5878ce09804129851510ea6790 I used `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `mkString`:

```
List(
  JSONObject(Map("hello" -> "world", "stackoverflow" -> "ishere")),
  JSONObject(Map("1" -> 1))
).map(_.toString()).mkString(", ")
```

Yields:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

List(
  JSONObject(Map("hello" -> "world", "stackoverflow" -> "ishere")),
  JSONObject(Map("1" -> 1))
).map(_.toString()).mkString(", ")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res2: String = {"hello" : "world", "stackoverflow" : "ishere"}, {"1" : 1}
```

Comment: Actually I have not just simple string list but collection with JSONObject elements

Comment: @Orest Then why not ask a question regarding `List[String]` if you actually have a `List[JsonObject]`? Where do these `JSONObject` types come from?

Comment: Sorry missed it

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
val s = List("JSONObject", "JSONObject", "JSONObject")
val result = s.mkString("[",",","]")
result: String = [JSONObject,JSONObject,JSONObject]
```